# Annals of John Hyrcanus

Tags: history, old-testament, 1-maccabees

### 1 Maccabees 16:23-24

> The rest of **John's acts**, the battles he fought and the exploits he
>   performed, the city walls he built, and all his other achievements,
>   from the day he succeeded his father as high priest, **are recorded in
>   the annals of his pontificate**.

Have these annals ever found?